# Nginx certbot : manually set up pem files to serve subdomain and main domain on https

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, certbot

I have two sites in folders like:

```
/var/www/my_site
/var/www/example.com
```

The first one is served a subdomain of the second one (subdomain.example.com).

I used certbot to enable ssl and https followed the instruction:

https://www.nginx.com/blog/using-free-ssltls-certificates-from-lets-encrypt-with-nginx/

Particularly:

```
sudo certbot --nginx -d example.com -d www.example.com
```

certbot automatically included the lines below not just for the main domain site, but also for 
the ngixn conf of the subdomain: I don't how it could do so, because I also have other subdomains but those nginx configurations were not affected.

```
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
```

Nginx fails to serve the subdomain site with this configuration, so I tried to edit the lines by changing the example.com to subdomain.example.com, but did not work:

```
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/subdomain.example.com/fullchain.pem; # edited manually
```

How to register a certificate for the subdomain site, so to serve it on https as well ?
Can / Should I use a different ssl certificate, or could use the same one as the main domain?

Can you guide to register manually , e.g. generating / adding the pem files ?

I also want to redirect http to https, but having conflicts between subdomain and main domain.

Comment: Your `certbot` command generated a single certificate for the `example.com` and `www.example.com` domains only, and linked it to `/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/`. You haven't generated a certificate for `subdomain.example.com` yet. Also, `--nginx` is not guaranteed for work for complex configurations, so you may be better off adding the `ssl_` statements manually.

Comment: I tried adding the ssl statements manually, but did not figure out how to manually generate a certificate for subdomain.example.com . When I used the command above `certbot --nginx ` for example.com, he also modified the nginx configuration of the subdomain site in the `my_folder`, I thought because the command go through all the nginx configurations and see if there was example.com mentioned in the servers, even if some other configurations remained untouched in spite of being subdomains too.

Comment: In reply to your comment  : "Also, --nginx is not guaranteed for work for complex configurations, so you may be better off adding the ssl_ statements manually." 
Instead of creating a ssl for each subdomain, better to use wildcard ?
https://medium.com/@saurabh6790/generate-wildcard-ssl-certificate-using-lets-encrypt-certbot-273e432794d7

Comment: I have never tried the `--nginx` option or wildcard domains. I use `certbot certonly --webroot -w ... -d ...` for each subdomain. Try the wildcard domain, it may be the better solution for you, IDK